# Do Edges and Rippertech stack?

Tags: savage-worlds, campaign-settings

So I was perusing the Rippers Ressurected book and found that there is rippertech that gives +d4 to unarmed damage, and was wondering if that would stack with the Martial Artist edge, giving a total of Str+d4+d4.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that indicates that they don't stack so yes, if you have that ripper tech and that edge then you would get the bonuses from both.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, would there ever be a reason something like rippertech and edges (generally) can’t stack?

Comment: I can think of no general rules - if such did exist they would have to be in the rippertech section of the rulebook and a quick flick through showed no such thing. If something says you get X bonus then you get it unless it explicitly says otherwise. For example claws explicitly notes "when using no other weapon".